# Is this set open, dense, in $[0,1]^\mathbb{Z}$ with the Supremum Metric?

Tags: general-topology, trigonometry, solution-verification

Let $X = [0,1]^\mathbb{Z}$.  I had never seen this notation before, so I'll just mention that  $[0,1]^\mathbb{Z}$ represents the functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $[0,1]$, kind of like sequences but with negative entries as well. We can define the metric $d$ on $X$.
$$d(x,y) = sup |x(n) - y(n)|$$
Where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then let $E =  (0,1)^\mathbb{Z}$ and ask whether $E$ is open or dense.

My first reaction is yes to both questions. It seems like $E = B(f, \frac{1}{2})$ where $f(n) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. In other words, if you're a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $(0,1)$ all your entries are at most $\frac{1}{2}$ from $\frac{1}{2}$. Is this correct?

What is the closure of $E$? If a function has $y(n) = 1,0$, then it is in the closure of the ball $B(f, \frac{1}{2})$, so the closure of the ball contains all of $X$. Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E\ne B(f,\frac12)$. For example the function $g:n\mapsto 1-1/(|n|+1)$ is in $E$ but
$d(f,g)=\frac12$.

Comment: In fact show that $g \in E$ but $g$ is not an interior point of it. So $E$ is not open. But it's easily seen to be dense, even in the product topology, which is coarser.